# Java assertions - second argument evaluation?

Tags: java, assert

I'm curious about the performance of Java assertions.
In particular, with 2-argument Java assertions, like this one:

```
assert condition : expression
```

Does "expression" get evaluated even if "condition" evaluates to true? I'm curious if it's a feasible solution for cases when we want super lightweight "condition", but "expression" can be too heavy (e.g. String concatenation). Solutions like e.g. Preconditions in Guava will evaluate the expression, making it infeasible for such cases.

My tests suggest it's lazily evaluated, but I couldn't find any reference proving it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can test it by calling a non-void method that prints out a message when it is called.

Comment: Yeah, I tested it, but I wanted a formal proof - the fact that one implementation does something, doesn't know it's guaranteed. Bruno's answer points to the "official" guarantee :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always refer to the Java Language Specification (JLS), http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.10

In short, you will find there that the second expression is lazily evaluated.

I highly recommend you bookmark the JLS. The table of contents is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html . The VM Spec might also be useful (you can find it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/)

Also, please note that assertions are in no way a substitute for things like Guava's Preconditions (or `if` statements testing for preconditions). They have a similar, but not identical, purpose. For instance, they can be disabled in runtime!

Comment: Perfect, this helps. Thanks! And yes, it's only for "development" assertions, not user errors etc.

Comment: Java assertions can indeed be disabled in runtime.  In fact ... this is the -default- behavior.  In order to be evaluated, Java assertions have to be specifically enabled with the -ea switch.